# Get Custom Location with map api in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, dictionary, location

Is there a way to get a custom location with pin when a user tap on a certain location in the map api of windows phone 8

Comment: What do you mean by "custom location with pin" Can u pls explain

Comment: Like get the lat,long of a certain location and pin means a marker/pushpin

Comment: You need to use map events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj208787%28v=vs.105%29.aspx to get geo coordinates of tapped location

Answer (score 2):

Not sure with it, but you can give it a try.

Subscribe to MouseLeftButtonDownEvent event of the map control you are using.

And in that event get the tapped point position like this.

```
private void myMap_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
             Point p1 = e.GetPosition(myMap);
        }
```

Now map in wp8 supports methods to convert View Port Coordinate to Geo Coordinate and vice versa, The former is the one you are looking for.

Add one more to the event handler. And your event handler would look like this.

```
private void myMap_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
             Point p1 = e.GetPosition(myMap);
             GeoCoordinate gc= myMap.ConvertViewportPointToGeoCoordinate(p1);
        }
```

Now as you have got the GeoCoordinates you can easily put pushpin on that location.

Hope this helps